# type annotation with inheritance in python

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, type-hinting, base-class

I am trying to provide type hints for a class init method, that uses child classes of a specific base class. Gooling how to do this tells me to use `Type[BaseClass]` as annotation, however inspections keep telling me i'm wrong.

As an example for my problem, let's say this is `base.py`:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        return
```

..and another `class.py`...

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, some_param: Type[B]):
        self.sp = some_param
```

Now, using these classes in the following way in a third file `test.py` brings forth some confusion for me:

```
from base import B
from class import SomeClass 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SomeClass(B())
```

I would have guessed this to be correct, yet the pycharm inspections underline it with the hint:

> Excpected type 'Type[B]', got 'B' instead

So since this didn't work, I figured I might need to use a `TypeVar`, so I changed `base.py` to:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        return

TB = TypeVar('TB', bound=B)
```

and `class.py` to:

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, some_param: Type[TB]):
        self.sp = some_param
```

However, this merely changes the pycharm inspection to say:

> Excpected type 'Type[TB]', got 'B' instead

Finally, if I set `class.py` to:

```
class SomeClass:

    TB = TypeVar('TB', bound=B)

    def __init__(self, some_param: Type[TB]):
        self.sp = some_param
```

The inspection error in `test.py` is gone and there are no complaints from pycharm!

(Curiously though, there are still complaints if I move `if __name__ == '__main__': sc = SomeClass(B())` to `class.py`.)

As I said I'm a bit puzzled as to how to truly use base classes with typing in Python:

- Is this all just a pycharm error?

If not,

- why is `Type[B]` not enough/working?
- why would one need to specify a `TypeVar` within the class and can't simply **import** the `TypeVar`?

Comment: Why not just use `B` instead of `Type[B]`?

Comment: `def __init__(self, some_param: B)` doesnt work?

Comment: `Type[B]` is the annotation for the the *class* `B` not instances of that class/type. You seem to be mistaking classes for their instances. Your class doesn't use "uses child classes of a specific base class" it uses *instances* of child classes of that specific base class. As others have noted, you simply want `B` not `Type[B]`

Comment: Yes I want to use instances of the base class or any derived class of it, which is why I figured I need Type[B] as per the docs of mypy:

"Sometimes you want to talk about class objects that inherit from a given class. This can be spelled as Type[C] where C is a class. In other words, when C is the name of a class, using C to annotate an argument declares that the argument is an instance of C (or of a subclass of C), but using Type[C] as an argument annotation declares that the argument is a class object deriving from C (or C itself)."
I fail to see the misunderstanding, what is my mistake?

Comment: `Type[B]` is used if you want to pass `B` itself (or a subclass of `B`) as an argument. You want to pass an *instance* of such a class, so you want `B` as the annotation. `B` and `Type[B]` are two entirely separate things.

Comment: `TypeVar` is basically for defining aliases to complex (or for use with `Generic`, unknown) classes.

Comment: If `C` is a subclass of `B`, an instance of `C` is *also* considered an instance of `B`, despite the fact that the *type* of `C` is not `B`.

Comment: Thanks to you all for the helpful comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Type[B]` is for indication that the argument should be a class object itself.

For example,

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

def foo(x: Type[B]):
    pass

foo(A)    # fails
foo(B)    # passes
foo(C)    # passes
foo(B())  # fails - an instance of B is not B or a subclass of B
```

You just want `B` as the type hint, to allow an *instance* of `B` (or a subclass of `B`) as an argument.

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, some_param: B):
        self.sp = some_param
```

Comment: This was precisely the issue. I misunderstood the mypy docs when they talked about "class objects", not seeing that it refers to the class itself as an object literally. I had presumed object to mean instance as well. Thanks a lot for the clarification.